# Google Maps API v3: search for map in a container

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple Google Maps on a page. After I initialized them, I have a need to change options for one, which is in a particular container. So, as I understand, I need to get a variable, which contains the link to this map.

The question is: how can I get the link for the google map if I know its container (for example, `$("#map1")`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };   

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the initialization step. But how can I find this "map" variable later, if I know only that it is contained by #map1?

Comment: hmm - I see the problem.  Looks like the only way is to define map as a global variable.  Not a great solution.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Only solution I found as well. Any way, a should need a global array to contain all the maps on the page. Looks crappy, but that is life. Any more ideas are welcome!